# Django saving in a model with User field

Tags: python, django

I have token auth implemented in django and my models looks like-

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User', null=True)
  company = models.TextField(null=True)
  volume = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
  date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

And to save in this model, I have the following in views-

```
arr = []
contents = request.data
user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
user_is = User(username=user)
  for i in range(0, len(portfolio_contents)):
    line = portfolio_contents[i].split(",")
    get_isin = Endday.objects.get(company=line[0])
    datestuff = line[2]
    datestuff = datestuff[0:10]
    arr.append(Portfolio(owner=user_is, company=line[0], volume=line[1], date=datestuff))
  Portfolio.objects.bulk_create(arr)
```

This code saves the data but when I try to see the data, I get this-

```
[
{
    "company": "BAL",
    "volume": 1425,
    "date": "2014-02-19",
    "owner": null
},
{
    "company": "RLD",
    "volume": 2245,
    "date": "2014-02-19",
    "owner": null
},
```

Owner should not be **null** because if I try to `print(user.username)`, it prints `<QuerySet [<User: ku>]>`.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't save your user e.g. it doesn't have an id in database.
Also you need a `User` instance and not `QuerySet` which you'll get from calling `User.objects.filter(username=request.user)`.

Try to:

```
user_is = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_is` is a `User` model instance which is not *saved* in the database:

```
user_is = User(username=user) # ??? username != user
```

---

Why not do:

```
user_is = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

Or make `owner=request.user` in the `ForeignKey` field in your loop.